# Why $\frac{1}{9}$ becomes $\frac{1}{3}$ in $\frac{1}{3} \int \frac{1}{s^2+1} \, ds$?

Tags: calculus

I'm trying to compute:

$$\int\frac{1}{x^2+4x+13} \; dx$$

And I'm following the steps given by W|A here:

> [image]

I don't understand why the $\cfrac{1}{9}$ becomes $\cfrac{1}{3}$ when the new substitution is made. If I switch the $s$ back to what it was, I'll get $u^2/9$ and I still need to multiply it by 9 to get $u^2+9$. I don't get why I need to change it to $1/3$.

---

**EDIT:**

$$u=x+2$$

$$s=\frac{u}{3}=\frac{1}{3}\cdot u$$

$$ds=\overbrace{\left[\frac{1}{3}\right]'u+\frac{1}{3}[u]'}^{\text{Product rule}}$$

$u=x+2$ and $u'=1$, I guess the trick is here: Instead of writing $u'$ in the product rule above as $1$, you write it as $du$.

$$ds=\left[\frac{1}{3}\right]'u+\frac{1}{3}[u]'=0\cdot u+\frac{1}{3}\cdot du=\frac{1}{3} \cdot du$$

$$ds=\frac{1}{3}du$$

"Solving" for $du$, we have:

$$3 ds=du$$

And then we switch the $ds$ with $yds$, where $y$ is whatever we have as a coefficient of $ds$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have
$$
\frac{1}{9}\int \frac{1}{\frac{u^2}{9} + 1} \; du = \frac{1}{9}\int \frac{1}{\left(\frac{u}{3}\right)^2 + 1} \; du.
$$
With the substitution $s = \frac{u}{3}$ you get $ds = \frac{1}{3}du$ or $\color{green}{3 ds} = \color{red}{du}$. So
$$\begin{align}
\frac{1}{9}\int \frac{1}{\left(\frac{u}{3}\right)^2 + 1} \; \color{red}{du} 
&=\frac{1}{9}\int \frac{1}{s^2 + 1} \; \color{green}{3ds}\\
&= \frac{\color{green}{3}}{9}\int \frac{1}{s^2 + 1} \; \color{green}{ds}\\
&= \frac{1}{3}\int \frac{1}{s^2 + 1} \; ds
\end{align}
$$

Comment: I don't understand why I have $ds=\cfrac{1}{3} du$. I don't understand how does $ds$ relates do $du$.

Comment: I've added an edit. Could you take a look at it?

Comment: @Voyska: I see your edit. You don't have to use the product rule. Recall the rule that says that $\frac{d}{dx} cf(x) = c\frac{d}{dx} f(x)$. That is, you can leave constants alone when they are multiplied by a function.

Comment: Okay. But is it wrong to use the product rule? Or it's just more practical to use this rule?

Comment: @Voyska: It is not "wrong" to use the product rule.

Answer (score 6):

Because $du = 3ds$, then the $3$ cancels out with the $9$ at the bottom to get you back $3$.

Answer (score 2):

The problem goes from having a factor of $1/9$ out in front to a factor of $1/3$ because of the change from $du$ to $ds$. Notice that
\begin{equation}
\frac{1}{9}du = \frac{1}{9}3ds = \frac{1}{3}ds. 
\end{equation}